# HTML - Either browser or handlebars is removing / ignoring a <table><tr><td> tag

Tags: html, node.js, google-chrome, handlebars.js

I have a *table* class that I use to vertically centralise text in a *span* or *div*. I am using Handlebars in Node to render several templates server side, I have used this method on several partials in my web project, with no problems.

However in one particular partial / area of markup, either the browser or Handlebars is ignoring or removing the *table*, *tr* and *td* tags, showing only the text that is inside the tags.

In the past when this has happened it was because my tags were incorrect. However I have cross checked this code with my other markup where the *table* tags do show (in other partials), so I can't see where the problem is, and I can't find any suitable online topic about this (it is probably something really obvious that will make me look like a dummy).

I have tried in Chrome and Edge. I have also tried saving the markup snippet in a .html file (as opposed to a .hbs file) and opening that in the browser, and by doing this it does show the *table* tags. The consequence of this error is that I am unable to vertically align the text in the *span*. I am not sure if the markup is invalid according to the browser or Handlebars, but I am not using any *{{Handlebars}}* tags here so it shouldn't warrant the *table* tags to be invalid.

Markup:

```
<div class="lp-menuselector" title="View summary of Individual Learning Plan and evidence pack">
 <div class="lp-menuselector-iconholder">
  <img src="icons/icon_lp-overview.svg"/>
 </div>
 <span class="lp-menuselector-textholder">
  <table class="tablecellleftalign">
   <tr>
    <td>
     ILP Overview
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </span>
</div>
```

Output markup shown in Chrome Developer Tools / Elements:

```
<span class="lp-menuselector-textholder">
            ILP Overview
          </span>
```

Answer (score -1):

Topic Closed:

After I restarted my computer and restarted the Node application, this error no longer occurs. Glitches in the matrix.

Comment: When a question doesn't have a real issue, don't answer it, delete it.